# How to get the class name to use to for an identifier or nibName without namespace?

Tags: ios, swift

In objective-c I used class names to pull nibs out of bundles or load viewControllers from storyboards like the examples below:

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:self options:nil].firstObject];`

`[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass(MyCustomViewController.class)];`

What is an equivalent way in swift to get the class name to use to for an identifier or nibName without namespace?

I have tried this

`mainBundle.loadNibNamed(NSStringFromClass(MyClass.classForCoder), owner: self, options: nil)`

but returns `MyTarget.MyClass` with namespace.

Comment: I'm possibly not understanding you question (out of lack of experience on the subject), so my apologies if this is off-topic or not. But regarding your last question: do you know of the instance suffix `.dynamicType`? E.g., `foo.dynamicType` is `Foobar.Type`.

Comment: Why are you using `classForCoder` at all? What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @matt - updated question to be more simple and clear.  Not sure what to use to accomplish this new question.  Somehow I landed on classForCoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what problem you're having, but the issue seems to be your insistence on passing through Objective-C Cocoa methods, which do indeed see the name of the Swift class as namespaced through the module. But this doesn't seem like much of an issue:

- You could, I suppose, just mechanically strip off the namespace (it is guaranteed to be everything up to and including the first dot).
- Alternatively, you could go the opposite way, and give the *.xib* file or the storyboard identifier the full namespaced name of the class. That works fine too.

However, there really seems to be no need for either of those approaches. I translated your first example:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:
    NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:self options:nil
        ].firstObject];
```

...directly, term for term, into this:

```
let v = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(
    String(self.dynamicType), owner:self, options:nil)
        .first
```

...and it worked perfectly: `v` ended up as (an Optional wrapping) the top-level view from inside the eponymous *.xib* file, which seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score -1):

Use `NSStringFromClass(MyClass.self)` instead of `NSStringFromClass(MyClass.classForCoder)` in your call.